# MySQL Fulltext search not working with more than 1 word

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

SQL:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST ('+htc +one') as Score
FROM `produkty`
WHERE MATCH (NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST ('+htc +one')
ORDER BY `TOP` DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

.htaccess rewrite search URL:

```
/vyhladavanie/+htc+one+/
```

If I search 1 word (e.g HTC) it works!

If I search 1+ words (e.g. HTC One) not working! Why?

Comment: You concept of "Not working" is *not compatible* with this website here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `produkty` WHERE MATCH (NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST('+htc +one' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `TOP` DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

try this